# Did any of the gentile prophets receive a divine message to be directed to the Jews?

Tags: talmud-gemara, gentiles, nevua-prophecy, bilam

Was Bilaam a prophet to both the Jews and the gentiles ?

According to the site member "Baby Seal":

> Bilaam's prophecy (Num 23, 24), contained much pertaining to Israel, and may have been his only prophetic experience (Nahmanides on Num 22:31).

Yet some other posters believe that gentile prophets weren't sent to the Jews at all and that their prophecies were directed only to the nations of the world.

Did any of the gentile prophets receive a divine message to be directed to the Jews, besides the gentiles?

Comment: Bailaam is one.